# Color program from Khanacademy with ProcessingJS

Tags: javascript

Recently I stumbled upon this Paintball animation from around seven years ago:

https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/paintball-painter/5316001292353536

It seems that this was build with [ProcessingJS](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) which is currently no longer maintained.
Thus why I want to try run it in vanilla javascript again.

When I look at the code in the link - also posted here, I think the only think I need to change or code myself is the `framerate(30)` at the start? When I looked for built in API for framerate I found requestAnimationFrame() in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947439/how-do-i-program-frames-per-second). Is this the way to go? I hoped to find the implementation of it in the [documenentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate) but thats not the case.

```
//Select your color on the bottom.
//click anywhere to shoot paintballs!

//This program works with modified canvas size. Just make sure you set this variable to the height
var canvasHeight = 400;

//https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/paintball-painter/5316001292353536?width=800&height=600


//0pink, 1red, 2orange, 3yellow, 4green, 5cyan, 6blue, 7purple, 8magenta, 9grey, 10black, 11random
frameRate(30);
var splatDiameter = 40;
var numSpots = 6;
var pcolor = 11;
var pballFrames = [1234, 1234];
var pballXs = [1234, 1234];
var pballYs = [1234, 1234];
var pballColors = [1234, 1234];
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var k = 0;
var spotXs = [1234, 1234];
var spotYs = [1234, 1234];
var spotColors = [1234, 1234];
var spotTrans = [1234, 1234];
var spotDiameters = [1234, 1234];
canvasHeight -=20;

var drawColorSelector = function(){
noStroke();
fill(255, 100, 130);
rect(0, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
fill(255, 0, 0);
rect(33, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
rect(363, canvasHeight, 37, 3);
fill(255, 140, 0);
rect(66, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
rect(363, canvasHeight + 3, 37, 3);
fill(255, 255, 0);
rect(99, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
rect(363, canvasHeight + 6, 37, 3);
fill(0, 200, 0);
rect(132, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
rect(363, canvasHeight + 9, 37, 3);
fill(0, 150, 150);
rect(165, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
fill(0, 0, 255);
rect(198, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
rect(363, canvasHeight + 12, 37, 3);
fill(150, 0, 150);
rect(231, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
rect(363, canvasHeight + 15, 37, 3);
fill(255, 0, 255);
rect(264, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
fill(150, 150, 150);
rect(297, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
rect(363, canvasHeight + 18, 37, 3);
fill(0, 0, 0);
rect(330, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
textSize(18);
text("?", 377, canvasHeight + 15);
noFill();
stroke(255, 255, 255);
strokeWeight(4);
if(pcolor < 11){
    rect(33 * pcolor, canvasHeight, 33, 20);
}else{
    rect(364, canvasHeight, 35, 20);
} 

};
var selectColor = function(){
    if(mouseIsPressed){
    if(mouseY > canvasHeight){
        if(mouseX < 33){
            pcolor = 0;
        }else if(mouseX < 66){
            pcolor = 1;
        }else if(mouseX < 99){
            pcolor = 2;
        }else if(mouseX < 132){
            pcolor = 3;
        }else if(mouseX < 165){
            pcolor = 4;
        }else if(mouseX < 198){
            pcolor = 5;
        }else if(mouseX < 231){
            pcolor = 6;
        }else if(mouseX < 264){
            pcolor = 7;
        }else if(mouseX < 297){
            pcolor = 8;
        }else if(mouseX < 330){
            pcolor = 9;
        }else if(mouseX < 363){
            pcolor = 10;
        }else{
            pcolor = 11;
        }
    }
}
};

var setFill = function(clr, trans){
    if(clr === 0){
        fill(255, 100, 130, trans);
    }else if(clr === 1){
        fill(255, 0, 0, trans);
    }else if(clr === 2){
        fill(255, 140, 0, trans);
    }else if(clr === 3){
        fill(255, 255, 0, trans);
    }else if(clr === 4){
        fill(0, 200, 0, trans);
    }else if(clr === 5){
        fill(0, 150, 150, trans);
    }else if(clr === 6){
        fill(0, 0, 255, trans);
    }else if(clr === 7){
        fill(150, 0, 150, trans);
    }else if(clr === 8){
        fill(255, 0, 255, trans);
    }else if(clr === 9){
        fill(150, 150, 150, trans);
    }else if(clr === 10){
        fill(0, 0, 0, trans);
    }else{
        fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), trans);
    }
};

var drawPaintball = function(x, y, frames){
    if(frames !== 1234){
        noStroke();
        ellipse(x, y, (11 - frames) * 3, (11 - frames) * 3);
    }
};

var spawnPaintball = function(){
    if(mouseIsPressed && (mouseY < canvasHeight || mouseX > 400)){
        for(i = 0; i < pballXs.length + 1; i += 1){
            if(pballXs[i] === 1234 || ! pballXs[i]){
                pballXs[i] = mouseX;
                pballYs[i] = mouseY;
                if(pcolor === 11){
                    pballColors[i] = floor(random(0, 10));
                }else{
                    pballColors[i] = pcolor;
                }
            pballFrames[i] = 1;
            i = pballXs.length + 2;
    }
}

}
};

var spawnSplat = function(x, y, dia, num, pclrid){
    for(k = 0; k < num; k += 1){
            j = spotXs.length;
            if( ! spotXs[j] || spotXs[j] === 1234){
               if(k === 0){
                   spotXs[j] = x;
                   spotYs[j] = y;
                   spotDiameters[j] = 30;
                   spotColors[j] = pclrid;
                   spotTrans[j] = 255;
               }else{
                   spotXs[j] = x + random(-dia/2, dia/2);
                   spotYs[j] = y + random(-dia/2, dia/2);
                   spotDiameters[j] = random(5, 40);
                   spotColors[j] = pclrid;
                   spotTrans[j] = 255;
               } 
            j = spotXs.length + 2;
            
            }
        
    }
};

var updatePaintball = function(){
    for(i = 0; i < pballXs.length; i += 1){
    if(pballXs[i] !== 1234 && pballXs[i]){
        setFill(pballColors[i], 1000);
        drawPaintball(pballXs[i], pballYs[i], pballFrames[i]);
        pballFrames[i] += 0.4;
        
        if(pballFrames[i] > 11){
            spawnSplat(pballXs[i], pballYs[i], splatDiameter, numSpots, pballColors[i]);
            pballFrames[i] = 1234;
            pballXs[i] = 1234;
            pballYs[i] = 1234;
            pballColors[i] = 1234;
        }
    }
}
};

var updateSpots = function(){
    for(i = 0; i < spotXs.length; i += 1){
    if(spotXs[i] !== 1234 && spotXs[i]){
        noStroke();
        setFill(spotColors[i], spotTrans[i]);
        spotTrans[i] -= 0.75;
        ellipse(spotXs[i], spotYs[i], spotDiameters[i], spotDiameters[i]);
        if(spotTrans[i] < 0){
            spotXs[i] = 1234;
            spotYs[i] = 1234;
            spotTrans[i] = 1234;
            spotDiameters[i] = 1234;
        }
    }
}
};


var draw = function() {
background(255, 255, 255);
selectColor();
spawnPaintball();
updateSpots();
updatePaintball();
drawColorSelector();
};
```

Now it seems after some reasearch that I probably just need to replace frameRate(30) with an own implementation in toder to not be dependent on a npm package. I looked at the old processingJS documentation but I could not find how they implemented the framerate() so I could see their implementation as I am unsure how to implement this function so the Paintball effect can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [p5.js](https://p5js.org/).

> p5.js is an interpretation of Processing for today’s web.

([editor](https://editor.p5js.org/), [creative community](https://openprocessing.org/))

It also includes the [`frameRate`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate) function.

If you are interested in the internals or want to replicate them in vanilla js: `frameRate` is located in [environment.js](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/core/environment.js#L292). It affects how often the [main animation loop](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/core/main.js#L367) (which is driven by [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)) triggers drawing.

edit: Here is a reputable example (lots of upvotes) [how to throttle requestAnimationFrame to a specific frame rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764018/controlling-fps-with-requestanimationframe/19772220#19772220).

edit: Your code [works pretty much out of the box with p5.js](https://jsbin.com/huyuzaroru/1/edit?html,js,output). All you need to do is to add a `setup` function that initializes the canvas, and the call to `frameRate` also needs to be located there:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  frameRate(30);
}

//insert your code
```

edit: To get started with p5.js, put your code in a file `sketch.js` and use the following HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

More instructions are available on the p5.js [*Get Started*](https://p5js.org/get-started/#sample-html) page.

Comment: Hey, sorry I guess I am missing something with p5.js but when I add the setup function that initializes the canvas and the call to framerate its not working out of the box? https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-grass-qeb0if?file=/src/index.js
And thanks for the tip where frameRate is located, I will dig into it!

Comment: added info on getting started. see your code working [here](https://jsbin.com/huyuzaroru/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

**It is very simple to port this ProcessingJS script to p5.js:**

https://editor.p5js.org/leftium/sketches/dKt3QEGFJ

Basically, replace `framerate(30)` with the following code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  frameRate(30);
}
```

The script will actually work without the call to `frameRate(30)`. It will just run faster at the default 60 FPS.

---

To help you rewrite in vanilla JS without p5.js:

- The [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate) for `frameRate()`
- The [source code](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/e2b15db57c9ab2517aabd6d22989166edf5dadda/src/core/environment.js#L292-L303) for `frameRate()`